# How can i show profile image (avatar) that is stored as a path in mySQL?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm storing images to a folder and the path to a database. It is successful, but i can't show the image (don't know how) **that is relevant to the logged in user.** I have tried with *php

```
echo img src="'.$path.'" alt=""
```

but it is not working i'm getting

> error: "Notice: Undefined variable: path in.. " can someone of you guys help me please?

This is my register.php code:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

//the form has been submitted with post
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


        //define other variables with submitted values from $_POST
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $fullname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);

        //md5 hash password for security
      //  $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        //  $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        //path were our avatar image will be stored
        $avatar_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/avatars/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);

        //make sure the file type is image
        if (preg_match("!image!",$_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {

            //copy image to images/ folder
            if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)){

                //set session variables to display on welcome page
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['avatar'] = $avatar_path;

                //insert user data into database
                $sql =
                "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fullname, avatar) "
                . "VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fullname', '$avatar_path')";

                //check if mysql query is successful
                if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration successful!"
                    . "Added $username to the database!";
                    //redirect the user to welcome.php
                    header("location: index.php");
                  }
                  else {
                      $_SESSION['message'] = 'User could not be added to the database!';
                  }
                  $mysqli->close();
              }
              else {
                  $_SESSION['message'] = 'File upload failed!';
              }
          }
          else {
              $_SESSION['message'] = 'Please only upload GIF, JPG or PNG images!';
          }
      }



?>
```

This is where i want to show the image after the user has been logged:

```
<div class="logged-user"> <!-- ova klasa -->
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
              <li class="list-inline-item py-2 align-middle">

              <p class="avatar mb-2"><?php echo '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="" />'; ?></p>

              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item py-2 align-middle mt-4">
                  <p class="nameofuser mb-2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["fullname"]); ?></p> <p class="position mt-1">The position</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

- DB NAME: employees
- DB Table: users (where i store user info and the    avatar path)

**UPDATE:** I found out how to show my image, i used: `<img src="<?= $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>"`

**Will PLEASE someone be so KIND**, and help me with the code with **REWRITING** it with **prepared parameterized statements** so i can **avoid SQL Injection Attack PLEASE**? Thanks a lot guys

Comment: So where did you assign a value to `$path` then? Where do you expect this to come from, I don’t see you reading from the database anywhere in the code snippets you have shown …?

Comment: you mean on this? :


        //path were our avatar image will be stored
        $avatar_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/avatars/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);

        //make sure the file type is image
        if (preg_match("!image!",$_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {

            //copy image to images/ folder
            if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)){

Comment: No, I don’t. That is there part where you write this data _into_ the database, not the part where you read it back from there after the user logs in.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Can someone please help me how to show the image? Example will be helpful. Thanks guys

Comment: Also, will PLEASE someone be so KIND, and help me with the code with REWRITING it with prepared parameterized statements so i can avoid SQL Injection Attack PLEASE??? Thanks a lot guys

Comment: BTW, i found out how to show my image, i used:

    <img src="<?= $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to show my image, i used:

```
<img src="<?= $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>"
```

Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

//the form has been submitted with post
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


        //define other variables with submitted values from $_POST
        $username = $_POST['username']; //remove mysqli_real_escape_string.its useless
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

        // dont use MD5..Use this hash method
         $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

       //YOUR DB QUERY
        if($sql =$YourDbConnectionVariable->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, fullname, avatar) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')")){
       $sql->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $fullname, $youravatarvariable);
       $sql->execute();
       $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration successful!"
                    . "Added $username to the database!";
        //redirect the user to welcome.php
       header("location: index.php");
}else{
code...
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
```